# Aurora RDS MySQL historical database recovery from historical snapshot and master snapshot?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0, amazon-rds-aurora

I was able to simulate a transactional cluster replicating to a historical cluster and it does all the changes, inserts, updates, deletes.  I was able to do an archiving delete so those deletes did not replicate to the historical cluster.  All is fine with the world until everything goes haywire and I need to restore the historical cluster.

I know I can have binlog enabled on the historical as well as the transactional.  what I am unsure about is how to recover the historical replication and start replication off at the correct point in time?

In historical setup, we used the snapshot of master transactional cluster and upon restore, it gives an event printing the binlog and offset to use to start replication which rocked.  In this case though, when the historical snapshot was taken, I am not sure of the offset, though in mysql docs, it implies the offset is passed through in A->B->C where B's bin log is just whatever A passed it.  is that true in RDS?

quoting mysql docs "Here, A serves as the source for the replica B, and B serves as the source for the replica C. For this to work, B must be both a source and a replica. With binary logging enabled and log_replica_updates enabled, which are the default settings, updates received from A are logged by B to its binary log, and can therefore be passed on to C."

If I use GTID, is the same true of GTID?  perhaps I should use GTID?